# Como buscar en una array de String por el inicio de los caracteres java

Tags: java

Hola buenas necesito hacer la siguiente operacion:

```
#Entrada "Busca el nombre en el array" buscador = an
#Proceso "Array de personas con DNI, NOMBRE, APELLIDO Y DIRECCION" 
        Alumnos paco = new Alumnos("12345678B", "Paco", "Manolo", "Calle alta");
        Alumnos paula = new Alumnos("87654321A", "Paula", "Baja", "Calle media");
        Alumnos nerea = new Alumnos("62716427C", "Nerea", "Valentina", "Calle alquitran");
        Alumnos Sofia = new Alumnos("65637718H", "Sofia", "De campos", "Calle antigua");
        Alumnos Antonio = new Alumnos("80228358B", "Antonio", "Martin","Calle Angel");
#Se coje el Buscador y se compara con todos los nombres del array hasta que uno coincida con el buscador
#Salida Los nombres que han coincidido con el buscador son: Antonio
```

No se como hacer esto llevo un rato dandole vueltas y he probado a realiarlo con compareto y con character pero no me acaba de funcionar.
Si alguien sabe como se podria hacer.
Muchas graciaas de antemano.

Comment: Creas una función getNomber() que retorne el nombre, luego un for que recorre el array y comparas con Equals

Comment: Hola Anthonyx82, tienes suficiente reputación, no deberías hacer este tipo de preguntas sin mostrar que has intentado... es invocar a los votos negativos.

Comment: Ok disculpa no lo sabia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que tienes un ArrayList alumnos = new ArrayList();

lo que deberías hacer es un bucle for que lo recorra y lo compare con el string que buscas

```
    ArrayList<Alumnos> alumnos = new ArrayList(); //Aquí tienes tu listado con los alumnos, paco, mario etc...
    ArrayList<Alumnos> alumnosCoinciden = new ArrayList();
    String stringBusqueda = //String del buscador;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<alumnos.length(); i++) {
       if(StringBusqueda.equals(alumnos.get(i).getName()) {
         alumnosCoinciden.add(alumnos.get(i);
        }
    }
```

alumnosCoinciden contiene al final del bucle todos los alumnos que coinciden con tu búsqueda.

Es pseudo código pero una solución básica sería algo así, si solo buscas coincidencia parcial sería contains() lo que quedarias de la siguiente forma:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<alumnos.length(); i++) {
           if(alumnos.get(i).getName().contains(StringBusqueda) {
             alumnosCoinciden.add(alumnos.get(i);
            }
        }
```

Espero sea útil

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona perfecto no habia caido ya que yo pensaba que como el equals devolvia un boolean luego no podia sacar la posicion del objeto pero si que podia por la "i" que recorrer el array